# Running Puppet upon system reboot and shutdown

Tags: systemd

we are looking for a way to trigger a Puppet run when the system shuts down or reboots. While it's relatively simple to have SystemD execute a script in one-shot mode this would not guarantee Puppet to have enough time to finish its work. Did anybody implement something similar or has some advise how to set this up?

Thanks

Comment: This seems similar to what you're trying to do:  https://serverfault.com/questions/771838/prevent-shutdown-until-execstop-script-completes

Comment: Thank you @satwell, indeed that was it

Answer (score 0):

From [Mocking](https://serverfault.com/users/350576/mocking)'s [answer on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/772062/293440):

---

I added the following and it worked:

```
TimeoutSec=300min
```

My final configuration is:

```
[Unit]
DefaultDependencies=no
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target
Before=reboot.target shutdown.target halt.target

[Service]
Type=simple
RemainAfterExit=true
User=test
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/test/test.py
ExecStop=/usr/bin/sh /home/test/test
KillMode=none
TimeoutSec=300min

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Note**: I purposely did not make the `TimeoutSec=infinity`